# multipart/form-data Cerberus FTP

Tags: powershell, post, file-upload, webrequest, mime-message

For the past week i´ve been trying to figure how to upload files to Cerberus FTP via HTTP request, but i keep getting the same response from the server.

If i change the contentype to something else it fails with a CSRF-check error.

Any ideas ?

It seems to be a formatting issue, but i cant figure where. In WinDiff the request is slighly off because there is an extra space after the Cookie attribute. Does this request type have to be 100% accurate in terms of spaces and such ?

In Fiddler the requests look identical.

Let me know if the website load script is required, the form didnt let me upload the entire script.

```
      "
Response: 
    HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
    Server: CerberusFTPServer/9.0
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-XSS-Protection: 1
    Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
    Referrer-Policy: same-origin
    Cache-Control: no-cache, private, must-revalidate
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Set-Cookie: cftpSID=w6QPdMOWDsO_wq-Dsw-Cj8KSw57CjwjDlQnDvistBw; Path=/; HttpOnly;
    Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2019 09:22:24 GMT
    Content-Length: 126

    {"files":[{"delete_type":"","delete_url":"","error":"Form data not complete","name":"","size":0,"thumbnail_url":"","url":""}]}"





#upload

$file = "C:\Users\michael\Desktop\1024000.txt"

    $fileName = Split-Path $File 
    $boundary = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()

    $fileBinary = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($File)

    $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")

    $fileEncoded = $enc.GetString($fileBinary)


$Uri='http://172.16.0.82/file/upload'

$ContentType = "text/plain"

$boundary = "-----------------------------7e3a63120b435"        

$FNAME = "1024000.txt"

$FileContent= $fileEncoded

$template = @' 
{5}
{0}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cd"

/
{0}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrftoken"

{4}
{0}
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="{1}"
Content-Type: {2}

{3}
{0}--

'@

$conn = "Connection: Keep-Alive"
$body = $template -f $boundary, $FNAME, $ContentType, $FileContent, $csrftoken, $conn


$ConType="multipart/form-data; boundary="+$boundary

$header=@{
'X-Requested-With'='XMLHttpRequest'
'Accept-Encoding'= 'gzip, deflate'
'Referer'='http://172.16.0.82/file'
'Content-Type'= "$ConType"
'Accept'='application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
'Pragma'='no-cache'
'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
'Host' = '172.16.0.82'
'Accept-Language' = 'en-DK,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,da;q=0.2'
}


Invoke-webrequest -Uri $Uri -Method POST -Body $body -Headers $header -websession $session
```

Comment: FTP and HTTP are two different protocols...  Why aren't you just using WinSCP to FTP files to the FTP server?

Comment: Because the script is required in an environment where FTP will not be available due to strict policies. But i agree, that would be the easy choice.

Comment: Usually you don't need to do all that extra work crafting your own request. In my experience, using `-InFile` is good enough.

Comment: Infile is returning the same.